# PHP Explode Remove "Extra" Text

Tags: php, explode

Assuming I have the following URL on a webpage, how I can I utilize the `explode()` function to give me only the ID, and not the rest of the URL that follows the ID?

```
file.php?id=12345&foo=bar
```

I can get the ID, but there's always the following "`&foo=bar`".

Thanks.

Comment: If it's a current request - then just `$_GET['id']`

Comment: No, I need to use `explode()` (or something similar). I'm lifting the URL directly from the webpage using cURL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a full URL, you can use `parse_url()` to get the query string part.

If it's just a fragment, you can use `explode()` to get it, then `parse_str()`:

```
list($path, $qs) = explode('?', $url, 2);
parse_str($qs, $args);
echo $args['id'];
```

The `2` tells `explode()` to break the string into a maximum of 2 parts (before and after the `?`, in this case).

Answer (score 5):

If you need to treat a valid URL, you can use

```
parse_url
```

[parse_url documentation](https://www.php.net/parse_url)

to explode the URL into different part (SCHEME, HOST, PORT, USER...)

and then, use

```
parse_str
```

[parse_str documentation](https://www.php.net/parse_str)

on the `QUERY` part, in order to retrieve an array containing all your parameters.
Then, you can catch what you need.

Comment: An important note about `parse_url` from the manual: "This function doesn't work with relative URLs."

Answer (score 3):

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
echo $id;
```

`parse_str` will create PHP-variables from query-string variables. 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php